# Can I use full URLs in iOS cache manifest?

Tags: ios, browser-cache

If I use a cache manifest for iOS Safari in order to cache pages offline, will it still work if I use a full URL, such as

```
https://example.com/content/folder/image.jpg
```

in the cache file, or do I *have* to use relative URLs?

Comment: could you please describe more what you want to know ? what do you mean by cache manifest?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html) clearly states:**

> The URLs are file paths to resources you want to download and cache
>   locally. The file paths should be relative to the location of the
>   manifest file—similar to file paths used in CSS—or absolute.

**So it should be relative URL.**

**But I also found an old [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html) that says**

> Resource URLs can be absolute or relative to the manifest file. Each
>   URL must appear on a separate line.

You should probably stick to the latest document and use relative URL only.